# Trying to end loop when user input = q

Tags: java

Essentially I am trying to create a Pig Latin converter. However, for this assignment a requirement is to allow the user to enter 'Q' to quit entering in words. I can get the code to compile, but whenever the user enters Q it crashes and throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at mission4aa.Mission4AA.main(Mission4AA.java:38)
```

I am just completley unsure where to even go about fixing this. I've been trying.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Mission4AA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        int firstVowel = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the pig latin translator!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a word (Q to exit): ");

        do {
            userInput = scanIn.next();
            userInput = userInput.trim();
            userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
            int end = userInput.length();

            char a = userInput.charAt(0);
            if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u' )
                System.out.println(userInput + "way");

            else { //Check for next vowel if the first letter is consonant
                for (int i = 1; i < userInput.length(); i++) { 
                    char b = userInput.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
                    if (b == 'a' || b == 'e' || b == 'i' || b == 'o' || b == 'u' ) {
                        firstVowel = i; //Stores the index of the first vowel 
                        break;        
                    }
                }
                if(userInput.charAt(1) != firstVowel) {
                    String startString = userInput.substring(firstVowel, end);
                    String endString = userInput.substring(0, firstVowel) + "ay";
                    String result = startString + endString;
                    System.out.println("Translation: " + result);

                }            

            } 
            System.out.println("Enter another word(Q to exit): ");
        } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));  
        System.out.println("Thank you");
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because if you enter just `Q` or `q` -  this will blow up - `if(userInput.charAt(1) != firstVowel) {`. There's no `char` at index `1`.

Comment: Why are you converting the input to lower case twice?  And what do you expect to happen if the input is a single consonant?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you are doing this check

```
if(userInput.charAt(1) != firstVowel) {
```

If the user has input a 'q', userInput will only have a 0 term ( Length 1 ). You are effectively trying to get the second character of the users input. To solve your problem, i would do the check for 'q' at the start of the do section ( or simply scrap the do-while concept and use a while(true) loop ). Note that in future you should handle input that is of length 1. But for your issue, something like this would work

```
do {
    userInput = scanIn.next();
    userInput = userInput.trim();
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
    int end = userInput.length();

    char a = userInput.charAt(0);
    //here
    if(userInput.equals("q") || userInput.equals("Q")){
        System.out.println("Thank you");
        return;
    }
    //else continue
```

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters just `Q` or `q` - there's no `char` at `index` `1`, which is why your code throws the `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

There are many ways to fix this. In my case, I just converted your `do-while` to a `while(true)` and I use `break` if the input is just `Q` or `q`.

```
// get first input
userInput = scanIn.next();
while(true){

    userInput = userInput.trim();
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

    int end = userInput.length();

    char a = userInput.charAt(0);
    if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u' )
        System.out.println(userInput + "way");

    else { //Check for next vowel if the first letter is consonant
        for (int i = 1; i < userInput.length(); i++) { 
            char b = userInput.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
                if (b == 'a' || b == 'e' || b == 'i' || b == 'o' || b == 'u' ) {
                    firstVowel = i; //Stores the index of the first vowel 
                    break;        
                }
        }
        if(userInput.charAt(1) != firstVowel) {
            String startString = userInput.substring(firstVowel, end);
            String endString = userInput.substring(0, firstVowel) + "ay";
            String result = startString + endString;
            System.out.println("Translation: " + result);

        }            

    }

    // check next word here - if Q or q, break out and finish
    userInput = scanIn.next();
    if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
      break;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter another word(Q to exit): ");
}
```

Note - you'd need to rearrange your print statements accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you read the user input in the beginning of the loop, thus the condition in your `do-while` loop checks the previous user input - not the new one.

In addition the else-branch of your `if-statement` assumes that the input is at least 2 characters long `if(userInput.charAt(1) != firstVowel) {...}`.

This is what causes the exception as the input `"q"` reaches the else-branch, but is only of length 1.

You need to make two changes to your code:

1. You need to read the userinput before checking the `loop-condition`.
2. In the else-branch you must check that the input is at least 2 characters long before checking if the second character is a vowel.

Modified code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    int firstVowel = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the pig latin translator!");
    System.out.println("Please enter a word (Q to exit): ");
    userInput = scanIn.next().trim().toLowerCase();

    do {
        int end = userInput.length();

        char a = userInput.charAt(0);
        if (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u' )
            System.out.println(userInput + "way");

        else { //Check for next vowel if the first letter is consonant
            for (int i = 1; i < userInput.length(); i++) { 
                char b = userInput.toLowerCase().charAt(i);
                    if (b == 'a' || b == 'e' || b == 'i' || b == 'o' || b == 'u' ) {
                        firstVowel = i; //Stores the index of the first vowel 
                        break;        
                    }
            }
            if(end > 1 && userInput.charAt(1) != firstVowel) {
                String startString = userInput.substring(firstVowel, end);
                String endString = userInput.substring(0, firstVowel) + "ay";
                String result = startString + endString;
                System.out.println("Translation: " + result);
            } else { /* Handle handle input of length 1 */} 

        } 
        System.out.println("Enter another word(Q to exit): ");

        userInput = scanIn.next().trim().toLowerCase();

    } while (!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));  
        System.out.println("Thank you");
  }
```